# how to generate random rectangles in a pygame and make them move like flappy bird?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, game-development

1. I am a python beginner. I want to recreate chrome dino game. the random rectangle won't stop and the loop runs forever...please help me to stop the loop and make rectangles move.

Code:

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))


#red rectangle(dino)
x = 20
y = 400
width = 30
height = 42
gravity = 5
vel = 18
black = (0, 0, 0)
#ground
start_pos = [0, 470]
end_pos = [500, 470]
#cactus
x1 = 20
y1 = 30

white = (2, 200, 200)

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:

    clock.tick(30)

    pygame.time.delay(10)
    win.fill(black)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    #random rectangle generation
    for i in range(1):
        width2 = random.randint(25, 25)
        height2 = random.randint(60, 60)
        top = random.randint(412, 412)
        left = random.randint(300, 800)
        rect = pygame.draw.rect(win, white, (left, top, width2,height2))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        y = y - vel

    else:
        y = min(428, y + gravity)

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.draw.line(win, white, start_pos, end_pos, 2)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This looks like a valid "absolute beginner-level" question, and should be re-opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pygame.draw.rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) des not "generate" a rectangle, it draws a rectangle on a surface.
[`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is a rectangle object. Create an instance of `pygame.Rect` before the main application loop:

```py
obstracle = pygame.Rect(500, random.randint(0, 412), 25, 60)
```

Change the position of the rectangle:

```py
obstracle.x -= 3
if obstracle.right <= 0:
    obstracle.y = random.randint(0, 412)
```

And draw the rectangle to the window surface:

```
pygame.draw.rect(win, white, obstracle)
```

Example:

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

start_pos = [0, 470]
end_pos = [500, 470]
gravity = 5
vel = 18
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (2, 200, 200)

hit = 0
dino = pygame.Rect(20, 400, 30, 40)

obstracles = []
number = 5
for i in range(number):
    ox = 500 + i * 500 // number
    oy = random.randint(0, 412)
    obstracles.append(pygame.Rect(ox, oy, 25, 60))

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:

    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        dino.y -= vel
    else:
        dino.y = min(428, dino.y + gravity)

    for obstracle in obstracles:
        obstracle.x -= 3
        if obstracle.right <= 0:
            obstracle.x = 500
            obstracle.y = random.randint(0, 412)
        
        if dino.colliderect(obstracle):
            hit += 1
            
    win.fill(black)
    color = (min(hit, 255), max(255-hit, 0), 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(win, color, dino)
    for obstracle in obstracles:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, white, obstracle)
    pygame.draw.line(win, white, start_pos, end_pos, 2)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL The unit of the return value of `clock.tick()` is milliseconds. `200*time_interval//1000` would be a speed of 200 pixels per second. (The attributes of `pygame.Rect` are integral)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yea it is integral but it also accept floats and convert that to int.

Comment: Also it is very good idea to multiply all of your velocityies with time interval of your main loop. Just make that: ``time_interval = clock.tick(60)/1000`` instead of ``clock.tick(60)`` and use that as a movement: ``x_cor -= 3*time_interval`` , ``obstracle.x = x_cor``. Now your obstracle is moving 3 *pixel* every second.